# Sending an object from a client to a server

Tags: java, sockets

I want to implement a simple server, which is able to receive an object from a client. The object which is sent from the client is a subclass of the object which is received (cast) at the server side.

EDIT: If I use the same subclass "TestMessage" the correct string is printed on the server side. If I use the superclass "Message" (I want to do that because I need multiple message subclasses) The string is just null. So is there a specific property of ObjectInputStream which messes up my fields or the whole object if I cast to the superclass?

```
Payload on client side: Hello Server!
Payload on server side: null
```

I have created an abstract class Message, from which several subclasses can be derived:

```
public abstract class Message implements Serializable {

    private static Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * A 16-byte string (GUID) uniquely identifying the message on the network. 
     */
    private byte[] guid;

    /**
     * Indicates the type of message.
     */
    private byte messageType;

    /**
     * The actual content of the message.
     */
    private static String payload;

    /**
     * TODO change to protected?
     * @return payload
     */
    public static String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    /**
     * TODO change to protected?
     * @param payload
     */
    public static void setPayload(String payload) {
        payload = payload;
    }

    /**
     * @return guid
     */
     public byte[] getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    /**
     * @return messageType
     */
    public byte getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for a newly created message
     * @param messageType
     */
    public Message(byte messageType) {
        guid = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(guid);

         //TODO encrypt guid?

        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for a received message
     * @param guid
     * @param messageType
     */
    public Message(byte[] guid, byte messageType) {
        this(messageType);
        this.guid = guid;
    }
}
```

Now, i have derived a test message type TestMessage, which is sent from the client to the server.

```
public class TestMessage extends Message {

    private static byte TYPE_ID = (byte) 0x00;

    /**
     * @param payload
     */
    public TestMessage(String payload) {
        super(TYPE_ID);

        /**
         * TODO: Better practice to create a protected setter?
         */
        Message.setPayload(payload);
    }
}
```

Now the server is nothing special at all. It waits for a client to connect and reads a Message object from the stream. Here I get a ClassNotFoundException. I suppose the Server class does not know the Message class? Why so? Is it a problem that the client is sending a subclass of the class which the server reads? Or is there something wrong with the casting of my Message class?

```
public class TestServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int port = 9999;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

        Message incomingMessage = null;
        incomingMessage = (Message)objectInputStream.readObject();

        System.out.println("Payload: " + Message.getPayload());
    }
```

}

And finally, the client:

```
public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String serverAdress = "localhost";
        int port = 9999;

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAdress, port);

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

        TestMessage testMessage = new TestMessage("Hello Server!");

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(testMessage);
    }
}
```

Thank you guys in advance! I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should provide the full stack trace instead of full code. At least the lengthy interface code is not needed here.

Comment: Are the `Message` end `TestMessage` classes available in the servers classpath?

Comment: Every class is in the same package, so i thought that would be enough. Do you care to explain how to add them to the classpath? Thank you!

Comment: How do you run TestClient and TestServer. From command line or some IDE? Setting the classpath largely depends on that.

Comment: I start both from Eclipse. The whole src folder is in the classpath.

Comment: Ok, then simply edit your question and paste the error message with stacktrace from eclipse, so we can help you. Otherwise everyone is just guessing.

Comment: I am so sorry. The classpath was correct. It is possible to send the same subclass TestMessage if I cast to that specific subclass. What I want do do is send a specific subclass of Message on the client side and cast to the superclass Message on the server side, because there I don't know which kind of message I am receiving. Do I have to use some sort of advanced handlers to get the correct subclass? Sorry for the confusion and thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `null` is this:

```
    public static void setPayload(String payload) {
        payload = payload;
    }
```

Be aware of namespaces. This method assings a parameter to itself and then eventually the object is destroyed. If you want to assign the parameter to the static member you have to adress it properly by using `Message.payload`. But in this case using a static member is not a good idea.

This would be better because you want to de/serialize an object (not a class):

```
private String payload;

public String getPayload() {
    return payload;
}
public void setPayload(String payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}
```

Make sure to change the method calls in `TestClient/TestServer` accordingly.

A final hint: If you do not close the sockets in `TestClient/TestServer` you might end up with `java.net.SocketException`s when running both classes more than once (depending on your operating system).

Answer (score 3):

On the **receiving side** of your application you **hasn't the class defining your object** so it is not possible to deserialize it and build the instance.

That class must be present in both sides (client and server).

Check your classpath to see if that class is present or not. Eventually add the right jar (or .class).

Comment: the client, server and message classes are all in the same package. I thought that would be enough. Can you give me hint on how to add a class to the classpath of another class?

Comment: Not add a class to the classpath of another class, but add a class to the classpath of the JVM running your main. The simplest solution is add that class to both projects. Otherwyse add it as a parameter to the java launch command: java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses utility.myapp.Cool

Answer (score 1):

The `Message` class implementation is needed at the server side for the object sent from the client to be deserialized at the server. By that, what i mean is classpath of the server jvm (TestServer main class) should contain the jar which contains bytecode for the class `Message`.

Comment: Ok. This is just a test architecture, so every class is in the same project and the same package. I thought that would be enough. Do you care to elaborate on how to add the Message class to the classpath of the server class? If I have a look at the sources of the project in Eclipse, everything is included :/

Comment: how are you running the server and the client classes ?

Comment: The way im running the server and client classes is through IntelliJ Idea IDE. I have tried to demonstrate the same from command line as well, just to keep IDE related issues out of the picture.

Comment: It was a problem with a setter, as answered. Thank you guys.